# jQuery Mobile Event Handling

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

Having recently started developing using jQuery Mobile, I am slightly mystified by the behavior of the event detection. In standard jQuery, I could always use

```
$("#someId").on("click",doSomething());
```

and this would work. However, I have found using jQuery mobile that I have to bind the event handler to the entire document in the following way:

```
$(document).on("click","#someId",doSomething());
```

Does anybody have any idea why this is the case? Does jQuery mobile handle events in such a different way to jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard jQuery bindings work when you call them - i.e., when you load your page with `$("#someId").on("click",doSomething());` code, it will look for elements with `someId` identificator and bind `doSomething()` callback to it. But with jQuery Mobile, some elements are not present when you load the page. Instead, the elements are downloaded with AJAX, hence, the binding you did on the page load didn't catch those elements. That's why with jQuery Mobile you will usually use delegate event bindings (on older versions of jQuery those were called *live* bindings), that will work even for elements that are added to the DOM later on. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile many times makes the navigation with ajax, so the elements don't always exist in the DOM.

This why people use the *delegate event* binding.

Comment: It makes sense to do so if the elements don't exist because of navigation with ajax, but I still find it strange that jQuery mobile doesn't support direct event binding. Thanks for your answer though :)